# Powershell filter filenames with specific file extension

Tags: regex, powershell, filter

I am working on a Powershell script that will return a list of files based on a filtered set of names and a specific extension, which in this case of the `.pdf` extension file type. I currently have this set up in a `foreach` control structure.

So far I have done this:

```
$MechDWGFilterList = @('*ifc*','*mech*', '*permit*', '*final*', '*CD*')
$MechDWGFile = @()

# $MechDWGFolder contains 1 or more filtered full path files
$MechDWGList = Get-ChildItem -Path $MechDWGFolder -Filter *.pdf -r | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime 

$count = 0
foreach ($file in $MechDWGList)
{
    # Where the file name contains one of these filters
    foreach($filter in $MechDWGFilterList)
    {
        if($file.Name -like $filter)
        {           
            $MechDWGFile += $file
            $count += 1
        }
    }
}
```

But I would like to condense something like below where I can avoid having to create an additional object `$MechDWGFile` from the above code.

```
$MechDWGFilterList = @('*ifc*','*mech*', '*permit*', '*final*', '*CD*')
$MechDWGFilterList2 = 'ifc|mech|permit|final|CD' #Tried this regex expression as well

$MechDWGList = Get-ChildItem -Path $MechDWGFolder -Filter ($MechDWGFilterList).pdf -r | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime 
Write-Output $MechDWGList
```

I feel like I'm close, unless this is completely not doable without an iterative control loop. Help understanding this challenge would be greatly appreciated!

Some other background refernce info: PowerShell 5.1 is being used as Administrator, Windows 10 OS

Comment: `-Filter` won't work with regex, you could pass the result from `Get-ChildItem` to a filtering cmdlet such as `Where-Object`

Comment: @Screamcheese, is that gir?(:

Comment: @AbrahamZinala yesh :o)

Comment: Man of high class!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-Filter` only supports `*` and `?` wildcards. In this case you could pipe the result of `Get-ChildItem` to `Where-Object` for filtering:

```
$MechDWGList = Get-ChildItem -Path $MechDWGFolder -Filter *.pdf -r |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'ifc|mech|permit|final|CD' } |
    Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime
```

This would be basically like doing this with a `foreach` loop and an `if` condition:

```
$MechDWGList = & {
    foreach($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $MechDWGFolder -Filter *.pdf -r) {
        if($file.Name -match 'ifc|mech|permit|final|CD') { $file }
    }
} | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime
```

Comment: SantiagoSquarzon, I'm curious with a question. With the two ways you wrote the solution, which would be the more efficient for executing?

Comment: @Screamcheese very likely the second one will be faster, the first option is more memory friendly tho but since you're storing everything in memory (`$MechDWGList`) then there isnt much of a difference